# OpenSSL error alert handshake failure

Tags: openssl

When trying to connect to some websites OpenSSL fails to connect. I get this error with OpenSSL's `s_client`:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.airvistara.com:443 -debug
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x600060cf0 [0x600076e90] (346 bytes => 346 (0x15A))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 55 01 00 01-51 03 03 b7 94 61 d2 52   ....U...Q....a.R
0010 - 8e fa c5 5e 3d d0 0b 62-91 14 c3 21 d5 62 3a e8   ...^=..b...!.b:.
0020 - 27 1c 99 12 0c e8 1d e8-ea cf 15 00 00 b4 c0 30   '..............0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1   .,.(.$..........
0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 69-00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37   ...k.j.i.h.9.8.7
0050 - 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86-00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .6.........2...*
0060 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0   .+.'.#..........
0080 - 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 3f-00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...g.@.?.>.3.2.1
0090 - 00 30 00 9a 00 99 00 98-00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43   .0.........E.D.C
00a0 - 00 42 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29-c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c   .B.1.-.).%......
00b0 - 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41-c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02   .<./...A........
00c0 - 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0 08-00 16 00 13 00 10 00 0d   ................
00d0 - c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 15-00 12 00 0f 00 0c 00 09   ................
00e0 - 00 ff 02 01 00 00 73 00-0b 00 04 03 00 01 02 00   ......s.........
00f0 - 0a 00 3a 00 38 00 0e 00-0d 00 19 00 1c 00 0b 00   ..:.8...........
0100 - 0c 00 1b 00 18 00 09 00-0a 00 1a 00 16 00 17 00   ................
0110 - 08 00 06 00 07 00 14 00-15 00 04 00 05 00 12 00   ................
0120 - 13 00 01 00 02 00 03 00-0f 00 10 00 11 00 23 00   ..............#.
0130 - 00 00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06-01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05   .... ...........
0140 - 02 05 03 04 01 04 02 04-03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02   ................
0150 - 01 02 02 02 03 00 0f 00-01 01                     ..........
read from 0x600060cf0 [0x60007c3f0] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                              ......(
2348672:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handsha
 failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
...
```

My strong point is not with SSL so some guidance would be appreciated.  The client software works with nearly all sites but there are a few that give this error.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: To answer your question, use TLS 1.0 or above with SNI. The following works as expected: `openssl s_client -connect www.airvistara.com:443 -tls1 -servername www.airvistara.com`. `-servername` enlists the SNI extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The client software works with nearly all sites but there are a few that give this error.

As commented by jww - you don't get this error if you use [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

SNI is supported by all modern browsers, but outside of this it is not supported with older versions of Java (up to JDK6), python (up to 2.7.9), with some commonly used libraries on Android etc.

Since SNI is more and more a requirement (all of Cloudflare FreeSSL works only with SNI) the client software should be fixed to get SNI support.

Comment: Thanks jww and Steffen, this answered my question.

Comment: One more question.  How did you determine SNI was the issue?

Comment: As you can see from the `openssl s_client` output it fails without the `-servername` option and succeeds with. Apart from that I have my own tool for SSL analyis https://github.com/noxxi/p5-ssl-tools/blob/master/analyze-ssl.pl. This gives (among other things): `SSL upgrade fails without SNI`.

Answer (score 11):

Use this method...

```
 $ openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -servername www.example.com
    CONNECTED(00000003)
    ...
       Cipher    : ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

It might be that the -servername option is not available with OpenSSL 0.9.8, but it should be with OpenSSL 1.0.1.

Comment: Ideally this should be have been the accepted answer.